# Is there any way to get a value of an attribute on the up-sell list with not active "Used in Product Listing" option?

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, up-sells

I want to get a value of the attributes on the up-sell list but only ones that have active "Visible on Product View Page on Front-end" option and not active "Used in Product Listing" option